# org-mode call python source within latex source block

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have a piece of python code that outputs latex code. I'm trying to call the python source block from within a latex source block so it will format the output as latex when I export.

Any idea how to do this? I was hoping something similar to the below would work.

```
#+name: gradient_potential
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports none :results output
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, diff, latex

x, y = symbols('x y')

U = x * y

print(latex(diff(U, y)))
#+END_SRC


#+begin_export latex
\begin{align}
#+CALL: gradient_potential() :results output
\end{align}
#+end_export
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Noweb reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Noweb-reference-syntax.html) `<<src block call>>` to inject the results of source blocks into other source blocks.

Example:

```
#+NAME: ltxInput
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none :results raw drawer
"\\sqrt{x^2+y^2}"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: ltxInput
:results:
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
:end:


#+NAME: ltxSrc
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :noweb yes :exports results
\begin{align*}
<<ltxInput()>>
\end{align*}
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: ltxSrc
#+begin_export latex
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{align*}
#+end_export
```

Tested with Emacs 26.3 and Org 9.2.6.

Note that your approach with the `:var` header argument of a `latex` source block did not work for me. I got an error `"Wrong use of \ in replacement string."` for the slash in `\sqrt{x^2+y^2}`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this, I'll post for anyone who has the same issue in the future. The method I found is using both a python source block and a latex source block.

```
#+name: gradient_potential_py
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports none :results output :cache yes
from sympy import symbols, diff, latex

x, y = symbols('x y')

U = x * y

print(latex(diff(U, y)), end='')
#+END_SRC

#+name: gradient_potential
#+begin_src latex :var expr1=gradient_potential_py :exports none
\begin{align}
expr1
\end{align}
#+end_src

#+CALL: gradient_potential()
```

I found that I need the `end=''` in the print statement when exporting to latex.